# Android Studio Gradle dependency ignored as it may be conflicting

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android studio and I need to use the following dependency:

```
compile 'org.jboss.resteasy.mobile:resteasy-mobile:1.0.0'
```

This dependency contains `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.3`
I get the following error by Android Studio:

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

How can I force to use my Dependency instead of the Android provided Dependency? Can I somehow exclude the httpclient from Android?

Thx.

Comment: That library is very old and includes Apache and Android has since removed Apache: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy.mobile/resteasy-mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 android {
     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

to tell android studio that you are using legacy library.